# Multipatch Editing

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

In ArcGIS JavaScript API, I try to edit my layer which contains buildings with multipatch geometries. In my web map, I create editor widget for edit my data but it does not work. Is it possible to edit multipatches using this editor widget, or how can I do this another way?
If there is a problem on my data, how can I fix them on ArcGIS Pro?

```
         const BuildingEdit = new SceneLayer({
           title: "Building Edit",
           url :"https://arcgis2.mipmap.nl/server/rest/services/Hosted/Region_02_Buildings_merged_R2_son/SceneServer",
              
       });


const editor = new Editor({
   view: view,
   allowedWorkflows: ["update","create", "create-feature","delete"], // allows only updates and no adds,
   
   layerInfos: [
     { //autocastable to LayerInfo type
       layer: BuildingEdit,
       allowDelete: true,
       //attachmentsOnUpdateEnabled: false // set this if wanting to remove the ability to select features in the editor with layers that have attachments and editing is enabled on them
     }
   ]
 });
```